# Need to install Python on work computers to compile into .exe

Tags: python

I developed a Python script that will run offline when needed (only for ~5 min/day) and handle some PHI. I wrote the script on a Mac and have been running it using Atom.

I need to get the program on 3 Windows computers here, but IT is hesitant about letting us install Python on the computers, since it could be a security risk. My plan was to move the code to a Windows computer and use pyinstaller and py2exe to make it a simple executable. I can't do that on my Mac, since it always tries to make a Mac application instead.

If I ever need to release updates to the script, I would have to keep Python installed on a Windows computer to do this. Is there any workaround that I can compile an .exe from a Python script using a Mac?

Comment: Parallels?  Also not sure this is really information security related, maybe server fault?

Comment: Do the Windows installer and conversion program run under Wine? It's worth investigating.